# Formatting transactional emails

Tags: email

How can I replace our store name with the customer's name in the "From" field when we receive new order emails? Makes more sense for us to see an order coming from a customer rather than our store name each time.  Thanks.

Comment: There is no question mark in your question. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Edited the question to include a question mark.

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: I think my question is pretty clear. I dont know how else to explain it, so while I appreciate your interest, I don't think you can help here.

Answer (score 1):

Since the email you get is a BCC (email copy) of what is sent to the customer editing the code would result in the customer seeing his own name in the order mail.

However in case you might want to change it. Check the class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` method `sendNewOrderEmail`. On line `1329` you will see the following code.

```
$mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
```

This is where the sender of the email is set.